# Netty packets and the bytebuffer framing?

Tags: java, encryption, netty, primitive

So I have an existing software package that uses Netty to communicate over an encrypted port between a client and a server.  Our issue started when we upgraded java from 1.8.073 to 1.8.161 and we saw our channel encryption handler fail.  We identified the change in the Oracle moved java's default RSA encryption to be 2048 as opposed to 1024 as it had been when you called the default constructor.  This issue was however that because the public key size had been 1024, its byte size was about 167 we would preface the packet with a random blob of 14 bytes and then send that through to the client to encrypt the channel.  No problem doing this with 73 however in 161 the key size when encoded to byte was (and I don't have my notes in front of me) about 269 or so ... 
We would read the random blob into the packet by encoding its length in the first byte then its data...then we would encode the key length in the next byte and then its data.  The problem was on decode.  To decode we would read the first byte to get the size of the random blob and then read the next byte to get the key size

```
public static void writeBlob(byte[] blob, ByteBuf buffer)
{
    if(debug) {
        //System.out.println("Buffer before writing:" + Arrays.toString(readBlob(buffer)));
        System.out.println("Blob before writing: Size:"+ blob.length+ " Content:" + Arrays.toString(blob));
    }
    buffer.writeByte(blob.length);
    buffer.writeBytes(blob);
    if(debug){
        //System.out.println("Buffer after Write: " + Arrays.toString(readBlob(buffer)));
    }

}

public static byte[] readBlob(ByteBuf buffer)
{
    if(debug) {
        //System.out.println("Buffer before writing:" + Arrays.toString(readBlob(buffer)));
        System.out.println("Buffer ready to read" );
    }
    int length = buffer.readUnsignedByte();
    byte[] data = new byte[length];
    buffer.readBytes(data);
    if(debug) {
        //System.out.println("Buffer before writing:" + Arrays.toString(readBlob(buffer)));
        System.out.println("Data : " + Arrays.toString(data));
    }
    return data;

}
```

The 2 things I noted where that the packet would adjust to being a full 512 byte packet as opposed to 256 bytes (obviously because it need that space to take that new enlarged key) however when I received it the packet was truncated to the exact size of the data  311 bytes, which was what I encoded.  The key length was being read at 38 bytes as opposed to the 267 it was encoded with.

The end effect for us was the initial encryption failed after the upgrade because the key byte data was being truncated.

Is anyone able to shed any light on what I have done wrong in my read/write code or is this likely to be further up my netty pipe.

[Link to the full code](https://github.com/AddstarMC/RemoteConsole/blob/master/Core/src/main/java/au/com/addstar/rcon/network/packets/RconPacket.java#L38-L67)

Addendum: this is the child class that handles the start of encryption.

```
public class PacketOutEncryptStart extends RconPacket
{
public PublicKey key;
public byte[] randomBlob;

public PacketOutEncryptStart() {}

public PacketOutEncryptStart(PublicKey key, byte[] randomBlob, boolean debug)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.randomBlob = randomBlob;
    this.debug=debug;
}

public PacketOutEncryptStart(PublicKey key, byte[] randomBlob)
{
    this(key,randomBlob,false);
}

@Override
public void read( ByteBuf packet )
{
    randomBlob = readBlob(packet);
    key = CryptHelper.decode(readBlob(packet));
}

@Override
public void write( ByteBuf packet )
{
    writeBlob(randomBlob, packet);
    writeBlob(key.getEncoded(), packet);
}

@Override
public void handlePacket( INetworkHandler handler )
{
    ((INetworkLoginHandlerClient)handler).handleEncryptStart(this);
}

}
```

Comment: What do you do with the bytes remaining/missing inside the buffers? The TCP layer does not guarantee that exact byte packets you send are the same size on the receiver side, only that the *stream*  is intact. Is there any code before this code that restores this framing?

Comment: I am just using the netty to automatically frame the packet.  The stream looks intact from both side I encoded 311 bytes and thats what came out the other end...

Comment: my issue is why the key length as it was written into byte 17 is not 267 instead we get 38

Comment: I am starting to think its because the initial auther chose to readunsignedbytes()

Comment: I don't see anything in your code where you write the results of your encryption

Comment: I have added the child class that covers

Comment: Ok so back and work and I have the data from debugging ...the key length was 162 on java73 and increased due to the new base 2048to  294 bytes.

Comment: So as well as the key we write the randomblob 14 bytes